# Finding repeated words on a string and counting the repetitions

Tags: java, string, repeat

I need to find repeated words on a string, and then count how many times they were repeated. So basically, if the input string is this:

```
String s = "House, House, House, Dog, Dog, Dog, Dog";
```

I need to create a new string list without repetitions and save somewhere else the amount of repetitions for each word, like such:

New String: "House, Dog"

New Int Array: [3, 4]

Is there a way to do this easily with Java? I've managed to separate the string using s.split() but then how do I count repetitions and eliminate them on the new string? Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You've got the hard work done.  Now you can just use a `Map` to count the occurrences:

```
Map<String, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for ( String word : splitWords ) {
   Integer oldCount = occurrences.get(word);
   if ( oldCount == null ) {
      oldCount = 0;
   }
   occurrences.put(word, oldCount + 1);
}
```

Using `map.get(word)` will tell you many times a word occurred.  You can construct a new list by iterating through `map.keySet()`:

```
for ( String word : occurrences.keySet() ) {
  //do something with word
}
```

Note that the order of what you get out of `keySet` is arbitrary.  If you need the words to be sorted by when they first appear in your input String, you should use a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Comment: using map.get(word) returns null. here's the documentation: 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html ----LATER EDIT: i saw that your key is String, so yea, it works, my bad.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
public class DuplicateWordSearcher {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "a r b k c d se f g a d f s s f d s ft gh f ws w f v x s g h d h j j k f sd j e wed a d f";

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(text.split(" "));

    Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>(list);
    for (String word : uniqueWords) {
        System.out.println(word + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, word));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

```
public class StringsCount{

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String value = "This is testing Program testing Program";

        String item[] = value.split(" ");

        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (String t : item) {
            if (map.containsKey(t)) {
                map.put(t, map.get(t) + 1);

            } else {
                map.put(t, 1);
            }
        }
        Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            System.out.println(key);
            System.out.println(map.get(key));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others use String::split(), followed by some map (hashmap or linkedhashmap) and then merge your result. For completeness sake putting the code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Genric<E>
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Map<String, Integer> unique = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (String string : "House, House, House, Dog, Dog, Dog, Dog".split(", ")) {
            if(unique.get(string) == null)
                unique.put(string, 1);
            else
                unique.put(string, unique.get(string) + 1);
        }
        String uniqueString = join(unique.keySet(), ", ");
        List<Integer> value = new ArrayList<Integer>(unique.values());

        System.out.println("Output = " + uniqueString);
        System.out.println("Values = " + value);

    }

    public static String join(Collection<String> s, String delimiter) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        Iterator<String> iter = s.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            buffer.append(iter.next());
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                buffer.append(delimiter);
            }
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

New String is `Output = House, Dog`

Int array (or rather list) `Values = [3, 4]` (you can use List::toArray) for getting an array.

Comment: Hi @Favonius.I want to load the strings from a text file and apply your code,Like this I want to get 2000+text files each separately apply your code and get output...Is this Possible?

Answer (score 2):

Using java8

```
private static void findWords(String s, List<String> output, List<Integer> count){
    String[] words = s.split(", ");
    Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Arrays.stream(words).forEach(e->map.put(e, map.getOrDefault(e, 0) + 1));
    map.forEach((k,v)->{
        output.add(k);
        count.add(v);
    });
}
```

Also, use a LinkedHashMap if you want to preserve the order of insertion

```
private static void findWords(){
    String s = "House, House, House, Dog, Dog, Dog, Dog";
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> count = new ArrayList<>();
    findWords(s, output, count);
    System.out.println(output);
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Output

```
[House, Dog]
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a homework, then all I can say is: use `String.split()` and `HashMap<String,Integer>`.

(I see you've found split() already. You're along the right lines then.)

Answer (score 1):

It may help you somehow.

```
String st="I am am not the one who is thinking I one thing at time";
String []ar = st.split("\\s");
Map<String, Integer> mp= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
int count=0;

for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
    count=0;

    for(int j=0;j<ar.length;j++){
        if(ar[i].equals(ar[j])){
        count++;                
        }
    }

    mp.put(ar[i], count);
}

System.out.println(mp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have got the words from the string it is easy.
From Java 10 onwards you can try the following code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StringFrequencyMap {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String[] wordArray = {"House", "House", "House", "Dog", "Dog", "Dog", "Dog"};
        var freq = Arrays.stream(wordArray)
                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()));
        System.out.println(freq);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{House=3, Dog=4}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*count no of Word in String using TreeMap we can use HashMap also but word will not display in sorted order */

import java.util.*;

public class Genric3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Map<String, Integer> unique = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        String string1="Ram:Ram: Dog: Dog: Dog: Dog:leela:leela:house:house:shayam";
        String string2[]=string1.split(":");

        for (int i=0; i<string2.length; i++)
        {
            String string=string2[i];
            unique.put(string,(unique.get(string) == null?1:(unique.get(string)+1)));
        }

        System.out.println(unique);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Prefix tree (trie) data structure to store words and keep track of count of words within  Prefix Tree Node.

```
  #define  ALPHABET_SIZE 26
  // Structure of each node of prefix tree
  struct prefix_tree_node {
    prefix_tree_node() : count(0) {}
    int count;
    prefix_tree_node *child[ALPHABET_SIZE];
  };
  void insert_string_in_prefix_tree(string word)
  {
    prefix_tree_node *current = root;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<word.size();++i){
      // Assuming it has only alphabetic lowercase characters
            // Note ::::: Change this check or convert into lower case
    const unsigned int letter = static_cast<int>(word[i] - 'a');

      // Invalid alphabetic character, then continue
      // Note :::: Change this condition depending on the scenario
      if(letter > 26)
        throw runtime_error("Invalid alphabetic character");

      if(current->child[letter] == NULL)
        current->child[letter] = new prefix_tree_node();

      current = current->child[letter];
    }
  current->count++;
  // Insert this string into Max Heap and sort them by counts
}

    // Data structure for storing in Heap will be something like this
    struct MaxHeapNode {
       int count;
       string word;
    };
```

After inserting all words, you have to print word and count by iterating Maxheap.

Answer (score 0):

```
//program to find number of repeating characters in a string
//Developed by Subash<subash_senapati@ymail.com>


import java.util.Scanner;

public class NoOfRepeatedChar

{

   public static void main(String []args)

   {

//input through key board

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a string :");

String s1= sc.nextLine();


    //formatting String to char array

    String s2=s1.replace(" ","");
    char [] ch=s2.toCharArray();

    int counter=0;

    //for-loop tocompare first character with the whole character array

    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
    {
        int count=0;

        for(int j=0;j<ch.length;j++)
        {
             if(ch[i]==ch[j])
                count++; //if character is matching with others
        }
        if(count>1)
        {
            boolean flag=false;

            //for-loop to check whether the character is already refferenced or not 
            for (int k=i-1;k>=0 ;k-- )
            {
                if(ch[i] == ch[k] ) //if the character is already refferenced
                    flag=true;
            }
            if( !flag ) //if(flag==false) 
                counter=counter+1;
        }
    }
    if(counter > 0) //if there is/are any repeating characters
            System.out.println("Number of repeating charcters in the given string is/are " +counter);
    else
            System.out.println("Sorry there is/are no repeating charcters in the given string");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="sdf sdfsdfsd sdfsdfsd sdfsdfsd sdf sdf sdf ";
    String st[]=s.split(" ");
    System.out.println(st.length);
    Map<String, Integer> mp= new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<st.length;i++){

        Integer count=mp.get(st[i]);
        if(count == null){
            count=0;
        }           
        mp.put(st[i],++count);
    }
   System.out.println(mp.size());
   System.out.println(mp.get("sdfsdfsd"));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a String argument it will count the repetition of each word

```
/**
 * @param string
 * @return map which contain the word and value as the no of repatation
 */
public Map findDuplicateString(String str) {
    String[] stringArrays = str.split(" ");
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArrays));
    int count = 0;
    for (String word : words) {
        for (String temp : stringArrays) {
            if (word.equals(temp)) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        map.put(word, count);
        count = 0;
    }

    return map;

}
```

output:

```
 Word1=2, word2=4, word2=1,. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class CountRepeatedWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          countRepeatedWords("Note that the order of what you get out of keySet is arbitrary. If you need the words to be sorted by when they first appear in your input String, you should use a LinkedHashMap instead.");
    }

    public static void countRepeatedWords(String wordToFind) {
        String[] words = wordToFind.split(" ");
        HashMap<String, Integer> wordMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String word : words) {
            wordMap.put(word,
                (wordMap.get(word) == null ? 1 : (wordMap.get(word) + 1)));
        }

            System.out.println(wordMap);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

public void countInPara(String str) {

```
    Map<Integer,String> strMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    List<String> paraWords = Arrays.asList(str.split(" "));
    Set<String> strSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(paraWords);
    int count;

    for(String word : strSet) {
        count = Collections.frequency(paraWords, word);
        strMap.put(count, strMap.get(count)==null ? word : strMap.get(count).concat(","+word));
    }

    for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry : strMap.entrySet())
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() +" :: "+ entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class DuplicateWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String para = "this is what it is this is what it can be";
        List < String > paraList = new ArrayList < String > ();
        paraList = Arrays.asList(para.split(" "));
        System.out.println(paraList);
        int size = paraList.size();

        int i = 0;
        Map < String, Integer > duplicatCountMap = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
        for (int j = 0; size > j; j++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (i = 0; size > i; i++) {
                if (paraList.get(j).equals(paraList.get(i))) {
                    count++;
                    duplicatCountMap.put(paraList.get(j), count);
                }

            }

        }
        System.out.println(duplicatCountMap);
        List < Integer > myCountList = new ArrayList < > ();
        Set < String > myValueSet = new HashSet < > ();
        for (Map.Entry < String, Integer > entry: duplicatCountMap.entrySet()) {
            myCountList.add(entry.getValue());
            myValueSet.add(entry.getKey());
        }
        System.out.println(myCountList);
        System.out.println(myValueSet);
    }

}
```

**Input:** this is what it is this is what it can be

**Output:**

[this, is, what, it, is, this, is, what, it, can, be]

{can=1, what=2, be=1, this=2, is=3, it=2}

[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2]

[can, what, be, this, is, it]

Comment: this does not need a nested loop. a linear parse over the words array would be good enough to check if a HashMap key exists, increment, else add an entry and set value to zero

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class class1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inpStr = in.nextLine();
    int key;

    HashMap<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    String[] strArr = inpStr.split(" ");

    for(int i=0;i<strArr.length;i++){
        if(hm.containsKey(strArr[i])){
            key = hm.get(strArr[i]);
            hm.put(strArr[i],key+1);

        }
        else{
            hm.put(strArr[i],1);
        }   
    }
    System.out.println(hm);
}
```

}

Comment: Few words would be better to explain your code, instead of just code.

Comment: 1. In Hashmap , words will be the key and occurance will be value  . If we are putting word first time in a hash map and related value will be 1 . Otherwise , we are incremented the value by 1 everytime when we are putting the same word  .

Comment: Please put this into the answer section not on the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code. It is the most simplest as per my analysis. Hope you will like it:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class MostRepeatingWord {

    String mostRepeatedWord(String s){
        String[] splitted = s.split(" ");
        List<String> listString = Arrays.asList(splitted);
        Set<String> setString = new HashSet<String>(listString);
        int count = 0;
        int maxCount = 1;
        String maxRepeated = null;
        for(String inp: setString){
            count = Collections.frequency(listString, inp);
            if(count > maxCount){
                maxCount = count;
                maxRepeated = inp;
            }
        }
        return maxRepeated;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        System.out.println("Enter The Sentence: ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = s.nextLine();
        MostRepeatingWord mrw = new MostRepeatingWord();
        System.out.println("Most repeated word is: " + mrw.mostRepeatedWord(input));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package day2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;`enter code here`
import java.util.List;

public class DuplicateWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String S1 = "House, House, House, Dog, Dog, Dog, Dog";
        String S2 = S1.toLowerCase();
        String[] S3 = S2.split("\\s");

        List<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < S3.length - 1; i++) {

            if(!a1.contains(S3[i]))
            {
                a1.add(S3[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }

            int Count = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < S3.length - 1; j++)
            {
                if(S3[j].equals(S3[i]))
                {
                    Count++;
                }
            }

            hm.put(S3[i], Count);
        }

        System.out.println("Duplicate Words and their number of occurrences in String S1 : " + hm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Counter {

private static final int COMMA_AND_SPACE_PLACE = 2;

private String mTextToCount;
private ArrayList<String> mSeparateWordsList;

public Counter(String mTextToCount) {
    this.mTextToCount = mTextToCount;

    mSeparateWordsList = cutStringIntoSeparateWords(mTextToCount);
}

private ArrayList<String> cutStringIntoSeparateWords(String text)
{
    ArrayList<String> returnedArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    if(text.indexOf(',') == -1)
    {
        returnedArrayList.add(text);
        return returnedArrayList;
    }

    int position1 = 0;
    int position2 = 0;

    while(position2 < text.length())
    {
        char c = ',';
        if(text.toCharArray()[position2] == c)
        {
            String tmp = text.substring(position1, position2);
            position1 += tmp.length() + COMMA_AND_SPACE_PLACE;
            returnedArrayList.add(tmp);
        }
        position2++;
    }

    if(position1 < position2)
    {
        returnedArrayList.add(text.substring(position1, position2));
    }

    return returnedArrayList;
}

public int[] countWords()
{
    if(mSeparateWordsList == null) return null;


    HashMap<String, Integer> wordsMap = new HashMap<>();

    for(String s: mSeparateWordsList)
    {
        int cnt;

        if(wordsMap.containsKey(s))
        {
            cnt = wordsMap.get(s);
            cnt++;
        } else {
            cnt = 1;
        }
        wordsMap.put(s, cnt);
    }                
    return printCounterResults(wordsMap);
}

private int[] printCounterResults(HashMap<String, Integer> m)
{        
    int index = 0;
    int[] returnedIntArray = new int[m.size()];

    for(int i: m.values())
    {
        returnedIntArray[index] = i;
        index++;
    }

    return returnedIntArray;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
//program to find number of repeating characters in a string
//Developed by Rahul Lakhmara

import java.util.*;

public class CountWordsInString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String original = "I am rahul am i sunil so i can say am i";
        // making String type of array
        String[] originalSplit = original.split(" ");
        // if word has only one occurrence
        int count = 1;
        // LinkedHashMap will store the word as key and number of occurrence as
        // value
        Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < originalSplit.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < originalSplit.length; j++) {
                if (originalSplit[i].equals(originalSplit[j])) {
                    // Increment in count, it will count how many time word
                    // occurred
                    count++;
                }
            }
            // if word is already present so we will not add in Map
            if (wordMap.containsKey(originalSplit[i])) {
                count = 1;
            } else {
                wordMap.put(originalSplit[i], count);
                count = 1;
            }
        }

        Set word = wordMap.entrySet();
        Iterator itr = word.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry map = (Map.Entry) itr.next();
            // Printing
            System.out.println(map.getKey() + " " + map.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Place some more explanation to your answer, not only code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String string = "elamparuthi, elam, elamparuthi";
    String[] s = string.replace(" ", "").split(",");
    String[] op;
    String ops = "";

    for(int i=0; i<=s.length-1; i++){
        if(!ops.contains(s[i]+"")){
            if(ops != "")ops+=", "; 
            ops+=s[i];
        }

    }
    System.out.println(ops);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to read the help page about [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). How is your answer different from all of those already provided?

Answer (score 0):

For Strings with no space, we can use the below mentioned code

```
private static void findRecurrence(String input) {
    final Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i<input.length(); ) {
        int pointer = i;
        int startPointer = i;
        boolean pointerHasIncreased = false;
        for(int j=0; j<startPointer; j++){
            if(pointer<input.length() && input.charAt(j)==input.charAt(pointer) && input.charAt(j)!=32){
                pointer++;
                pointerHasIncreased = true;
            }else{
                if(pointerHasIncreased){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(pointer - startPointer >= 2) {
            String word = input.substring(startPointer, pointer);
            if(map.containsKey(word)){
                map.put(word, map.get(word)+1);
            }else{
                map.put(word, 1);
            }
            i=pointer;
        }else{
            i++;
        }
    }
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + (entry.getValue()+1));
    }
}
```

Passing some input as "hahaha" or "ba na na" or "xxxyyyzzzxxxzzz" give the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :

```
public static int countOfStringInAText(String stringToBeSearched, String masterString){

    int count = 0;
    while (masterString.indexOf(stringToBeSearched)>=0){
      count = count + 1;
      masterString = masterString.substring(masterString.indexOf(stringToBeSearched)+1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package string;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class DublicatewordinanArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String str = "This is Dileep Dileep Kumar Verma Verma";
DuplicateString(str);
    }
public static void DuplicateString(String str) {
String word[] = str.split(" ");
Map < String, Integer > map = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
for (String w: word)
if (!map.containsKey(w)) {
map.put(w, 1);
    }
else {
map.put(w, map.get(w) + 1);
        }
Set < Map.Entry < String, Integer >> entrySet = map.entrySet();
 for (Map.Entry < String, Integer > entry: entrySet)
if (entry.getValue() > 1) {
 System.out.printf("%s : %d %n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
 }
}
```

Comment: An explanation might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 streams [collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
public static Map<String, Integer> countRepetitions(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split(", "))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, (a, b) -> a + 1));
}
```

Input: `"House, House, House, Dog, Dog, Dog, Dog, Cat"`

Output: `{Cat=1, House=3, Dog=4}`

Answer (score 0):

Use Function.identity() inside Collectors.groupingBy and store everything in a MAP.

```
String a  = "Gini Gina Gina Gina Gina Protijayi Protijayi "; 
        Map<String, Long> map11 = Arrays.stream(a.split(" ")).collect(Collectors
                .groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()));
        System.out.println(map11);

// output => {Gina=4, Gini=1, Protijayi=2}
```

In Python we can use collections.Counter()

```
a = "Roopa Roopi  loves green color Roopa Roopi"
words = a.split()

wordsCount = collections.Counter(words)
for word,count in sorted(wordsCount.items()):
    print('"%s" is repeated %d time%s.' % (word,count,"s" if count > 1 else "" ))
```

Output :

"Roopa" is repeated 2 times.
"Roopi" is repeated 2 times.
"color" is repeated 1 time.
"green" is repeated 1 time.
"loves" is repeated 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

please try these it may be help for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1="House, House, House, Dog, Dog, Dog, Dog";
        String str2=str1.replace(",", "");
        Map<String,Integer> map=findFrquenciesInString(str2);
        Set<String> keys=map.keySet();
        Collection<Integer> vals=map.values();
        System.out.println(keys);
        System.out.println(vals);
    }

private static Map<String,Integer> findFrquenciesInString(String str1) {
        String[] strArr=str1.split(" ");
        Map<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<strArr.length;i++) {
            int count=1;
            for(int j=i+1;j<strArr.length;j++) {
                if(strArr[i].equals(strArr[j]) && strArr[i]!="-1") {
                    strArr[j]="-1";
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count>1 && strArr[i]!="-1") {
                map.put(strArr[i], count);
                strArr[i]="-1";
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: From Review: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as introduction of stream has changed the way we code; i would like to add some of the ways of doing this using it

```
    String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
    
    //1. All string value with their occurrences
    Map<String, Long> counterMap = 
            Arrays.stream(strArray).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e->e, Collectors.counting()));

    //2. only duplicating Strings
    Map<String, Long> temp = counterMap.entrySet().stream().filter(map->map.getValue() > 1).collect(Collectors.toMap(map -> map.getKey(), map -> map.getValue()));
    System.out.println("test : "+temp);
    
    //3. List of Duplicating Strings
    List<String> masterStrings = Arrays.asList(strArray);
    Set<String> duplicatingStrings = 
            masterStrings.stream().filter(i -> Collections.frequency(masterStrings, i) > 1).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```